# WPF ListView scrollbars scroll everything

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollbar

I have the following ListView layout:

```
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <ListView Height="Auto" Name="lstvItems" Width="Auto" Background="#FF354D55" SelectionMode="Single" >
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Name:" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="100" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Type:" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Type}" Width="70" />
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </ScrollViewer>
```

If I add a border to the ListView and the scrollbars are available, the borders scroll along with the content.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ScrollViewer`.

The [Default `ListView` Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) already has a `ScrollViewer`.

Obtained from Expression Blend:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
    <!-- more content here -->
</ControlTemplate>
```